# I am making a web app that will be sealed with phonegap so it will run natively, my app is a game needed to be landscape

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html, cordova

I'm building a native web app that will be secured with `phone gap`

it's a game that require landscape mode. Is there any code I can use to force it landscape or is this impossible ?

Comment: setting `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` in manifest? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Comment: or <preference name="Orientation" value="landscape" /> in phonegap's config.xml